# Why are my iAds not displaying in the iPhone Simulator in iOS 4.1?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iad

I'm trying to display iAds in my application that is built against the iOS 4.1 SDK, but I am unable to see these ads in the iPhone Simulator.  In the videos that I have seen about integrating iAds in applications, the OS used was iOS 4.0.

Is there a problem with iOS 4.1 for displaying iAds, or what else could be going wrong in my application?

Answer (score 1):

iAd is for iOS 4.0 and above, so 4.1 should be fine.

Did you miss one of the step below...

- Add iAd.framework to your project
- #import <iAd/iAd.h> in your view controller .h file
- Drag and drop iAdBannerView to your interface
- Link adView variable and delegate using the interface builder
- Implement the delegate bannerViewDidLoadAd that show the ad
- Implement the delegate didFailToReceiveAdWithError that hide the ad

You can see the code below and adapt to your own need...

```
// RootView.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface RootView : UIViewController {
    BOOL bannerIsVisible;
    ADBannerView *adView;
}

@property (nonatomic) BOOL bannerIsVisible;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ADBannerView *adView;

@end
```

```
// RootView.m

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark iAd Banner

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {

    YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[appDelegate navigationController];

    if (self.bannerIsVisible == NO) {
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height);
        [navigationController view].frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 410);
        self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {

    YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[appDelegate navigationController];

    if (self.bannerIsVisible) {
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);
        [navigationController view].frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
        self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }
}
```